Linux VM clock behind after resuming from hibernate
I have Hyper-V on Windows 11 Enterprise 22H2.
One of the VMs is running OracleLinux 5.5 (based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.5).
Whenever I suspend (hibernate) the host machine and then later resume, the clock in the VM is behind, approximately for the amount the host was sleeping.
The VM integration services options are on, including Time synchronization.
Why is this happening and how to solve it?
Currently I just manually correct the system time on the VM on each occasion.

As far as I know Oracle 5.5 and/or RHEL 5.5 are point releases that were released close to 15 years ago and which have been considered  end-of-life and end-of-support since 2020. So guest integration with a much more modern hypervisor may simply not work properly. It was recommended to run a NTP client in RHEL guests, which may or may not suffer from hybernation and which may prevent the system from adapting the right time once it resumes, or alternatively, if it isn't already enabled, enabling NTP may be the solution for the clock issue

"RHEL 6.4 and later versions have built-in drivers that allow RHEL guests to run on Hyper-V hosts using synthetic devices."
